# Nodejs mongoose : how to retreive data from db collection related to other collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, relation

I want to implement a function that would process students, courses and instructors data (loaded from MongoDB collections) in order to produce information about students enrolled on courses (and store it in another MongoDB collection). the function reports each student’s:

```
primary key
their name
the number of courses they are enrolled in
```

I want to Store the output of this routine in a MongoDB collection called coursereport like this :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "jeff",
    "value": {
      "name": "Jeff Holland",
      "numbercourses": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "john.shore",
    "value": {
      "name": "John Shore",
      "numbercourses": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "lee2331",
    "value": {
      "name": "Lee Aldwell",
      "numbercourses": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "rcotter",
    "value": {
      "name": "Ray Cotter",
      "numbercourses": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "scott",
    "value": {
      "name": "Scott Mills",
      "numbercourses": 3
    }
  }
]
```

my data :

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "_id": "john.shore",
      "name": {"first": "John", "last": "Shore"},
      "email": "john.shore@gmail.com",
      "major": "Electrical Engineering"
    },
    {
      "_id": "jeff",
      "name": {"first": "Jeff", "last": "Holland"},
      "email": "jeff@yahoo.com",
      "major": "Business"
    },
    {
      "_id": "scott",
      "name": {"first": "Scott", "last": "Mills"},
      "email": "scott@hotmail.com",
      "major": "Humanities/Art"
    },
    {
      "_id": "rcotter",
      "name": {"first": "Ray", "last": "Cotter"},
      "email": "rcotter@msn.com",
      "major": "Computer Science"
    },
    {
      "_id": "lee2331",
      "name": {"first": "Lee", "last": "Aldwell"},
      "email": "lee2331@aol.com",
      "major": "Graphic Design"
    }
  ],
  "courses": [
    {
      "_id": "HIST-1010",
      "name": "History of the World 1010",
      "description": "A bunch of really interesting things that actually happened",
      "students": ["scott", "john.shore"],
      "ratings": [3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4]
    },
    {
      "_id": "ENGCOMP-1010",
      "name": "English Composition 1010",
      "description": "If you can't write well, you've got nothing!",
      "students": ["scott", "lee2331", "rcotter", "john.shore", "jeff"],
      "ratings": [4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5]
    },
    {
      "_id": "ART-1050",
      "name": "Artistic Interpretation 1050",
      "description": "Discover your inner beholder",
      "students": ["rcotter", "scott", "jeff"],
      "ratings": [3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4]
    }
  ],   
  "instructors": [
    {
      "_id": "wally.r.binns",
      "name": {"first": "Wally", "middle": "r", "last": "Binns"},
      "email": "wally.r.binns@ssu.edu",
      "bio": "I was born in the middle of my mother's doctoral dissertation on Faraday Cage isolation. I've been an academic ever since...",
      "publications": [{
        "title": "Inverted Celestial Poetry",
        "source": "http://www.pubcentral.com/poetry/inverted-celestial-poetry"
      }],
      "courses": ["ENGLIT-2500"]
    },
    {
      "_id": "gerald.waterford.iii",
      "name": {"first": "Gerald", "last": "Waterford", "suffix": "III"},
      "email": "gerald.waterford.iii@ssu.edu",
      "bio": "My father's father was a great man. My father, not so much. I am restoring the family honor.",
      "publications": [{
        "title": "Grow, grow, little Dandelion",
        "source": "http://www.hopefulstories.com/my-dandelion"
      }, {"title": "The teapot and the spoon", "source": "http://www.dishsoap.com/teapot-spoon"}],
      "courses": ["ENGCOMP-1010", "HIST-1010"]
    },
    {
      "_id": "kim.b",
      "name": {"prefix": "Mrs.", "first": "Kim", "last": "Binnley"},
      "email": "kim.b@ssu.edu",
      "bio": "My mother told me 'Don't let those dopes push you around'. My life has been a constant struggle against dopeness ever since. Sigh...",
      "publications": [],
      "courses": ["ART-1050"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I started with that :

```
async function produceReport(db, callback) {
  const students = db.collection('students');
  const courses = db.collection('courses');
  const instructors = db.collection('instructors');

  // implement missing code that will create 'coursereport' mongo collection with student courses data

  callback();
}

module.exports = produceReport;
```

can any one give a help please

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Defined as:

> To perform an equality match between a field from the input documents with a field from the documents of the “joined” collection,

So you have to join `students` and `courses` and later the output value with `instructors`..

Take a look at this query:

```js
db.students.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "courses",
      localField: "item",
      foreignField: "email",
      as: "students_courses"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "instructors",
      "localField": "students_courses._id",
      "foreignField": "courses",
      "as": "students_courses"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "value": {
        "name": {
          "$concat": [
            "$name.first",
            " ",
            "$name.last"
          ]
        },
        "numbercourses": {
          "$size": "$students_courses"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "value": 1
    }
  }
])
```

First stage is a joing with two collections with the fields indicated and soterd into a field called `students_courses`.
Then, another join with the `_id`s from the `students_courses`.

With the data then you can create a field named value with the name and count the number of courses in other field.

And `$project` to show only fields you want.

Check an example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q6UcMQNMUPc)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.students.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "courses",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "students",
      as: "students_courses"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      value: {
        name: {
          $concat: [
            "$name.first",
            " ",
            "$name.last"
          ]
        },
        numbercourses: {
          "$size": "$students_courses"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.